# How can I chain Export-CSV to Send-MailMessage without having to save the CSV to disk in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to email a list of AD users as a CSV but I don't want to have to save the CSV to disk before I email it.

Here is the code that gets me the data:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties Telephonenumber |
where Telephonenumber -ne $Null | 
select givenname, surname, telephonenumber | 
sort surname
```

Now I want to add on something like:

```
| Export-Csv | 
Send-MailMessage -From HelpDesk@company.com -to someone@company.com -subject "Outlook address book export" -SmtpServer EdgeTransport
```

Is there anyway to add the CSV data as an attachment in memory without saving the file to the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Attachments` parameter for `Send-MailMessage` requires an array of paths, so you must write a file to disk somewhere.

To send your CSV data as the body of the email, use `convertto-csv -notypeinformation` instead of `export-csv`.

```
$myData = get-aduser -filter * -properties Telephonenumber | where Telephonenumber -ne $Null | select givenname, surname, telephonenumber | sort surname|convertto-csv -notypeinformation
Send-MailMessage -From HelpDesk@company.com -to someone@company.com -subject "Outlook address book export" -SmtpServer EdgeTransport -body $mydata
```

Comment: One day I might try to get an in memory filesystem working with powershell but for now your answer is correct, you cannot attach files without first writing them to the filesystem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The proposed/accepted answer above is incorrect and won't work. The -Body parameter of the Send-MailMessage expects an string object (System.String). The $mydata object created in the example is a System.array object. If you use it as shown above the command will fail.

What you can do is create a file, fill it with the CSV data, email it as an attachment and then delete it.

Using your code above, for example:

```
$attachment = New-Item filename.csv -ItemType file
get-aduser -filter * -properties Telephonenumber | where Telephonenumber -ne $Null | select givenname, surname, telephonenumber | sort surname | Export-Csv $attachment -NoTypeInformation
Send-MailMessage -Attachments $attachment -Body $SmtpBodyTrue -BodyAsHtml -From $SmtpSender -To $MailTo -Subject $SmtpSubject -SmtpServer $SmtpServer
Remove-Item $attachment
$attachment = $null
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  I would suggest you edit this to provide a better answer than the one you are questioning before it gets flagged and removed.

Comment: Done. Now it is an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a super old thread, but the above answers are no longer correct.  You can send in-memory objects as attachments without writing to a file first.  You need to use .net methods, but it works well.

The key is the .net method [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString

http://geekswithblogs.net/mkoerner/archive/2012/01/19/powershell-emailing-strings-as-attachments.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but I thought I would give my input after being in a similar position.

The below is a basic function that I have written to create a CSV attachment from an object etc.

One of the main issues with getting this to work was firstly `convertto-csv` outputs everything in quotes (I know this has been fixed PS6 +, but not useful when using PS5. Secondly when casting the CSV data to a string and converting it to a memory stream it was escaping Carriage Return / Line Feed, to get around this I appended `[System.Environment]::NewLine` to every row in the CSV.

```
Function ConvertTo-CSVEmailAttachment {
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$FileName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Object]$PSObject,
    $Delimiter
    )
    If ($Delimiter -eq $null){$Delimiter = ","}
    $MS = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
    $SW = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($MS)
    $SW.Write([String]($PSObject | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $Delimiter | % {($_).replace('"','') + [System.Environment]::NewLine}))
    $SW.Flush()
    $MS.Seek(0,"Begin") | Out-Null
    $CT = [System.Net.Mime.ContentType]::new()
    $CT.MediaType = "text/csv"
    Return [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::new($MS,$FileName,$CT)
}
```

To use this you would require to have your object ready as their is no pipeline functionality taken into consideration (As I said basic function).

Example:

```
 $ADList = get-aduser -filter * -properties Telephonenumber | where Telephonenumber -ne $Null | select givenname, surname, telephonenumber |sort surname
 $EmailAttachment = ConvertTo-CSVEmailAttachment -FileName "ADList.CSV" -PSObject $ADList
```

One of the answers is correct in the sense that `Send-MailMessage` requires a string to a file path to function.

However you can use the .net library `[Net.Mail.MailMessage]` to create the email instead of using `Send-MailMessage`:

```
$SMTPserver = "This.Will.Be.Your.Email.Server.Endpoint"
$from = "SomeEmailAddress@yourdomain.com"
$to = "Recipient@domain.com"
$subject = "This is the subject Line"
$emailbody = "This is the body of the email"

$mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($SMTPserver)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $emailbody)
$msg.Attachments.Add($EmailAttachment) #### This uses the attachment made using the function above. 
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $false
$mailer.send($msg)
```

Anyway I hope this helps someone that is in a similar situation in the future.