# Send-MailMessage Attachment from memory

Tags: powershell, scripting, attachment

I am trying to send attachments in Send-MailMessage without saving to disk first by using the answer I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648761/how-can-i-chain-export-csv-to-send-mailmessage-without-having-to-save-the-csv-to), which points to [this URL](http://geekswithblogs.net/mkoerner/archive/2012/01/19/powershell-emailing-strings-as-attachments.aspx).

It says to use:

```
$attachment = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($attachmenttext,"test.txt")
```

But when I try to do that with Send-MailMessage instead of the complicated way it shows, I get this error:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "email@email.com" -To "email@email.com" -Subject "Subject" -Body $body -SmtpServer "smtp.server.local" -Port 25 -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $attachment

Send-MailMessage : Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\System.Net.Mail.Attachment'.
At line:3 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From "email@email.com" -To "email@e ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MailMessage], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Is there anyway to continue using Send-MailMessage with this method? Or is there a different method that will allow me to attach files without first saving to disk while still using send-mailmessage?

Comment: what type of item from memory. Is it a string or bytearray>

Comment: No, you'll have to construct and send the mail manually using the tools available in `System.Net.Mail` (`MailMessage`, `SmtpClient`, `Attachment` etc.)

Comment: @ArcSet a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first go over whats wrong. `[System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString` outputs type `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` while `send-mailmessage -attachments` is looking for an array of strings `string[]`. Thats why the example will fail.

I have written a simple function so you can use the attachment you have posted in the example which creates a `MailMessage` and looks for attachments of type `[System.Net.Mail.Attachment]`.

```
Function Try-SendMail([string[]]$To, [string]$From, [string]$SmtpServer, [int]$Port = 25, [pscredential]$SmtpCredential, [string]$Subject, [string]$Body, [System.Net.Mail.Attachment[]]$attachment, [switch]$IsBodyHTML){
    [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]$Mail = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $To | %{$Mail.To.Add($_)}
    $Mail.From = $From
    $Mail.IsBodyHtml = $IsBodyHTML
    $Mail.Body = $Body
    $Mail.Subject = $Subject
    $Attachment | %{$mail.Attachments.Add($_)}
    [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient]$SMTP = new-object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $SMTP.Host = $SmtpServer
    $SMTP.Port = $Port
    If($SmtpCredential){
        $NetCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential
        $NetCredential.UserName = $SmtpCredential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
        $NetCredential.Password = $SmtpCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
        $SMTP.Credentials = $NetCredential
    }
    try{
        $SMTP.Send($Mail)
    }catch{
        $_ | select *
    }
}
```

you can use it like

```
$To = @("Person1@Test.com","Person2@Test.com")
$From = "MainGuy@PErson.com"
$Server = "SMTPSERVER.NET"
$Port = 587
$Attachments = @(
    $([System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString("HELLO", "Test.txt")),
    $([System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString("HELLO2", "Test2.txt"))
)
$SmtpCredential = Get-Credential

Try-SendMail -to $To -From $From -Subject "Hello" -Body "World" -Attachment $Attachments -SmtpServer $Server -port $Port -SmtpCredential $SmtpCredential
```

*Edited forgot to make `[System.Net.Mail.Attachment]` to `[System.Net.Mail.Attachment[]]` in the function parameters

Comment: Thank you - I was hoping for an one-liner I could remember, but I can live with that. I can copy and paste the function and use the rest like I normally would. Shame this is not built in to the send-mailmessage!

Comment: Well its official - I used this method. I was torn between your method or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955860/filename-of-downloaded-file-in-dataapplication-octet-stream). I loved the other method because it was more customization and easy to remember, but it doesn't work in Outlook 2016. If I could give you multiple upvotes I would :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: @alexander7567 most email client will not allow that method you linked